# Software System Design Architecture IIS Server 7.5 and .NET Core (3.X or 2.X)( with Web API) compatibility issues & Design issues

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-core-2.1

We have a project to complete that involves using an Old Existing Web Application developed and deployed with following technologies:

-.NET Framework 4

-developed Using Visual Studio 2010 (VS2010)

-Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

-IIS Version 7.5

- 8 GB RAM

-Telerik\RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2011

We have a new project that involves creating a Csv File uploader for the web application.
Our proposed plan was to UI uploader Csv File Uploader component on the Old Existing Web Application.
However, we Want to use Newer technology for the main quasi-ETL processing of the Csv Data.
As we Brainstorm, we came up with the following technologies that could be used for the main quasi-ETL processing of Csv Data.

- .NET Core (3.X or 2.X)
- Visual Studio 2019

However, we have to deploy the Old Existing Web Application ( which would contain the UI Csv File Uploader) and the new main quasi-ETL processing of Csv Data to the same Web Server which would mean using the following slightly old technologies:
-Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

-IIS Version 7.5

-8 GB RAM

I'm in the process of developing a - .NET Core (3.X or 2.X) Web application, and deploying it in an environment that uses:

-Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

-IIS Version 7.5
**Please Keep in mind that both the Old Web Application and the New .NET Core application will be deployed on the same IIS Server 7.5**

[image]

The Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Server & IIS Server hosts a lot of important applications so I am concerned about what kind of modifications/update/add-on  that I might have need to install.

-Does anyone know about any possible technical compatibility problems or troubles that I might face? If yes, what could it be?

-To elaborate, within the Control Panel's "Turn Windows Feature on or off", could you please tell me what might need to be enabled for .NET Core (3.X or 2.X)(  with Web API) to work on said IIS Version 7.5?

-Also, may I please know if I have to install any Microsoft module executable ( or something similar)?

-Also, please feel free to suggest improvements Or tell me about any pitfalls/obstacles that I might face.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is end of life, so I wonder why you would like to stick to a dead product. Other than that, .NET Core 2.1/3.1 was designed to work in the scenario you described, as it can run side by side with your old ASP.NET 4.x apps. Microsoft has clear documentation on almost everything you need to know, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: However, may I please know if I have to change any configuration within the Control Panel's "Turn Windows Feature on or off" section?

Comment: Anything coming from Control Panel is shipped with IIS. However, ASP.NET Core module is out-of-band, so you need an extra download, not from Control Panel. I believe Microsoft documented that very well, so read it.